# Modifying the transparency of a gradient for a transparent arc on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, transparency

Here I have an arc with some transparency applied to one of the two gradients its using:`

```
ctx.arc(mouseX,mouseY,radius,0, 2*Math.PI,false);
var grd=ctx.createRadialGradient(mouseX,mouseY,0,mouseX,mouseY,brushSize); 
grd.addColorStop(1,"transparent");
grd.addColorStop(0.1,"#1f0000");
ctx.fillStyle=grd;
ctx.fill();
```

Is there a way to now give the entire arc some transparency affecting only the arc and none of the rest of the canvas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike SVG or HTML, there is no layering or grouping on an HTML Canvas. You can't wrap your arc/gradient in another lower-opacity element; you must propagate opacity (or tinting, or whatever) changes down to the end properties directly.

Your color `#1f0000` is equivalent to `rgb(31,0,0)`; use rgba to lower the opacity of this particular color stop.

```
var opacity = 0.55; //55% visible
grd.addColorStop(1,'transparent');
grd.addColorStop(0.1,'rgba(31,0,0,'+opacity+')');
```

Comment: Thanks Phrogz. This does the trick but I've been seeing a lot of artifacts when I draw. Take a look at this screen :http://imgur.com/MG5ck The image should not have those "chunks" missing. Any idea why this happens? Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the code producing it, my only guesses would be either a) something related to non-full paths with a fill arcing between the stop and end points, b) many paths created without `beginPath/closePath/moveTo` between them, c) some implementation-specific canvas bug.

Comment: It was b. Im going to keep experimenting with this but as it is now using actual images (instead of arcs) look much better on what Im doing. Thanks again.

Comment: Just found that safari 10.1 on macOS 10.12 does not support rgba color stop

Answer (score 0):

You could make the color stop at the end an rgba color and give it transparency that way.

Comment: Can you give a quick example? Thanks